# open docs or docs file in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, file-handling

I'm new to handling files so I'm trying to open .doc or .docx files using laravel 4.2. Then display it in a textarea with a ckeditor class in my controller. Here is how I access the file:

```
$userDoc = "uploads/docs/" . $fname;

    $fileHandle = fopen($userDoc, "r");
    $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($userDoc));   
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
    $opendoc = "";
    foreach($lines as $thisline)
      {
        $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
        if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
          {
          } else {
            $opendoc .= $thisline." ";
          }
      }


    $opendoc =preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$opendoc);

    return View::make('dmy.open_doc' , compact('title', 'smpl' , 'opendoc'));
```

Then I use it in my view like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'spot', 'method' => 'post')) }}

    @foreach($smpl as $list)
    @endforeach

    <p>{{ Form::text('fid',  $list->fileid, array('style' => 'form-control')) }}</p>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor" id = "stuff">
        {{ $opendoc }}
    </textarea> 
    {{ Form::submit('Go', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close()}}
```

Unfortunately the stuff I'm getting are only random character, but I'm able to read the text file though. Any ideas on how to do this properly? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What is $smpl? Why foreach loop ends quickly?

Comment: hi! those are records from the database i just used foreach to get the values because if not some errors would appear

Comment: You have passed  'smpl' from controller to view but you haven't declared it in controller action.

Comment: You can use variables in "view" file  if you have passed it and declared it  in "controller"

Comment: You can't read doc/docx as plain text, You need some kind of library.

Comment: hi @GiedriusKiršys do you have any suggested library? thanks so much

Comment: @BourneShady try googling `php word` and you will get a lot of results, such as: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord - A pure PHP library for reading and writing word processing documents